# ReactJS: how to make two backend requests at once?

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, parallel-processing, axios

Is it possible to make two backend requests at once from react?

The code below is the first backend call. The post request gets send to the backend and then I would like to do another request. Is it possible at all? Or do I have to wait for the backend response until the next request could be made? 
What I basically want is to get information about how many files have been uploaded. The upload could take 3 minutes and the user right now only sees a loading icon. I want to additionally add a text like `"50 of 800 Literatures uploaded"` and 10 seconds later `"100 of 800 litereratures uploaded"`.

This is basically my code :

```
class ProjectLiterature extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

      isLoading:"false",
}
}
  addLiterature(data, project_name) {

    this.setState({ isLoading:true }, () => {
      axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/sendLiterature", data })
        .then(res => {

          this.setState({ isLoading: false })
        })
    })
  }
```

Comment: Are your requests done in sequence (ie. do you need data from the first call in the second)?

Answer (score 1):

If both requests do not depend on each other, you can make use of JavaScript's [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) for the above purpose.

```
const request1 = axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/sendLiterature');
const request2 = axios.get(url2);

Promise.all([request1,request2]).then([res1, res2] => {
  // handle the rest
}).catch((error) =>  {
  console.error(error);
  // carry out error handling
});
```

If the second request relies on the response of the first request, you will have to wait for the first request to be completed as both requests have to be carried out in sequence.

```
const res = await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/sendLiterature');
// carry out the rest
```

Comment: If any of the request fails it will come to the catch block which means even one is success it will come to failure, so you need to handle that condition also. Add that part also so it will be helpful for him to consider that part also.

Comment: what do you mean with "depend"? So the first request is a post request which posts literature to the database. The second request is a get request which gets the amount of literature which has already been added to the database. So e.g. if the first request posts 800 objects to the database and is half completed, there are 400 literature objects in the database and the second request should get e.g. the backend resonse with the value "400". So it kind of depends on the first request

Comment: Ahh.. I see.. In that case, you shouldn't use `Promise.all` or `Promise.allSettled`. You will have to wait for the first request to be completed, before the second request can be fired.

Comment: so there's no way to call the backend in parallel every 20 seconds and check e.g. the length of the database to know how many objects already have been uploaded?

Answer (score 0):

You can see [axios docs](https://github.com/axios/axios#concurrency) for this purpose, they support multiple requests out of box.
You can use `Promise.all` instead of `axios.all` as well but if one of requests fails then you won't be able to get response of successful calls. If you want get successful response even though some calls fails then you can use `Promise.allSettled`.